# Group dataframe rows by day

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a `data.frame`, `df`, with two variables, `date` and `y`:

```
>df
                date      y
 2020-03-08 00:20:22  0.2713602
 2020-03-08 00:24:35 -0.1118034
 2020-03-09 14:56:00  0.2834734
 2020-03-09 23:41:37 -0.2687936
 2020-03-12 13:49:38  0.3535534
 2020-03-12 22:45:27 -0.2500000
 2020-03-12 22:46:45 -0.4596194
```

such that:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  2 variables:
$ date : POSIXct, format: "2020-03-08 00:20:22" "2020-03-08 00:24:35" ...
$ y: num  0.271 -0.112 0.283 -0.269 0.354 ...
```

I would like to group rows by day, averaging the corresponding `y` values, e.g. something like this

```
>result
       date      y
 2020-03-08  0.0797784
 2020-03-09  0.0073398
 2020-03-12 -0.1186887
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the 'date' to `Date` class and use that as grouping variable and then do the `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
   summarise(y = mean(y))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
aggregate(y ~ cbind(date = as.Date(date)), df, mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

With `data.table` :

```r
library(data.table)
df[, .(y = mean(y)), by = as.Date(date)]
```